# Django: a related model values list as part of a values list query

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to figure out if its possible to set up a query which would act something like `Model.objects.values_list('id', 'related_model__ids')` and return something like `[(1L, [2L, 6L]), (2L, [1L,]), (3L, [1L, 3L, 4L, 5L]), ...]` Here are some specifics:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    positions = models.ForeignKey(Position)
    ...

>>> # players 31, 32, 33 play multiple positions, and I want a result to be
>>> # [(player.id, [a list of position.id for all positions]), ...]

>>> Player.objects.filter(id__in=[31, 32, 33]).values_list('id', 'positions__id')
[(31L, 13L), (31L, 7L), (32L, 13L), (32L, 8L), (33L, 13L), (33L, 7L)]
```

This `values_list` query produces multiple tuples for the same `id` value, two entries for `id=31`, `id=32` and `id=33`. When I make a `values_list` query on a specific player (`id=31`), I get the list of position ids I would like:

```
>>> p31 = Player.objects.get(id=31)
>>> position_ids = p31.positions.values_list('id', flat=True)
>>> type(position_ids)
<class 'django.db.models.query.ValuesListQuerySet'>
>>> position_ids
[13L, 7L]
>>>
>>> # I want [(31L, [13L, 7L]), (32L, [13L, 8L), (33L, [13L, 7L)]
>>> # Without have to do something like a list comprehension:
>>> # [(p.id, list(p.positions.values_list('id', flat=True))
>>> #     for p in Player.objects.filter(id__in=[31, 32, 33])]
```

No doubt a list comprehension will yield the result I would like. I wanted to avoid multiple individual queries to the database with each `list(p.positions.values_list('id', flat=True))` forcing the resolution of a `ValuesListQuerySet` into an actual list. Of course, if I don't force the resolution, an operation on the result of the list comprehension would seem to execute a fresh `p.positions.valuse_list('id', flat=True)` query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, I wish there were some grouping query method as well.

I recently had to do something similar with highly nested models to avoid some crippling database calls. I ended up using `values()` to efficiently get all the, umm, values I needed. Then, stitched everything together as a dictionary in pure Python. It ended up miles more efficient, but of course the customization has its own maintenance downside.

The gist of it, using the Author/Book models:

```
# models.py
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

Then in a view (or a shell in my case) construct the dictionary you can pass to your template:

```
>>> authors = Author.objects.prefetch_related('book_set').values('id', 'book')
>>> print authors
    [{'book': 1, 'id': 1}, {'book': 2, 'id': 1}, {'book': 2, 'id': 2}]
>>> author_dict = {}
>>> for a in authors:
    if a['id'] not in author_dict:
        author_dict[a['id']] = set()
    author_dict[a['id']].add(a['book'])
>>> print author_dict
    {1: set([1, 2]), 2: set([2])}
```

Not the answer you probably wanted, but it's the only thing I have come up with. I'd love to hear if anyone else has solved the problem with some native Django method.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your answer reflects what I am actually working on. Too many of the search query's I run hit the db hard, so I am writing a model which saves the both the means to run certain queries and their results. The next step for this is to figured out how to have a custom model manager check to see if query results are saved or if it needs to run a query and save the results. Have you looked at tying your dictionaries in with model queries?

Comment: I haven't. Generally, when I can no longer optimize my queries using Django's syntax (non-SQL statements), it's time to split the web server from the database server across different machines (a good idea anyway if you have the resources). Then it's either more hardware or custom SQL if possible. Also, note the use of `prefetch_related` which can be much faster than `select_related` in some cases.

Comment: Also, forgot to mention it but there is a fantastic DB debugger for Django called the [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar). You may already be using it, but I wanted to add that for anyone else who stops by.

Comment: Recently, I started to run `python manage.py debugsqlshell` constantly, and likewise started to use `prefetch_related` and `select_related`. Thanks for the example uses for those filters. My goal add custom queries to extend the QuerySet API, and also have manager calls to the custom QuerySet check to see if the result is already a python data object like you describe. I find chaining QuerySet filters to be highly legible and intuitive, even if the logic underneath is complicated by the use of python data objects.

Comment: Here's another way to create the dict from your code:`import defaultdict; author_dict = default_dict(set); for author in authors: author_dict[author['id']].add(author['book'])` which gives `defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {1: set([1, 2]), 2: set([2])})`. Wish I knew how to format this comment with line breaks.